# Using linq to Return list of objects where sum of attribute is the Max() in list of list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of a lists of objects (`List<List<Product>>`). I want to return just one list of list where the `sum` of the `cost` in the internal list is the highest.

Am trying to use a linq query in C# to achieve this. Am not too familiar with these linq queries though.

```
List<List<Product>> query = (from lists in ListOfList
                            where lists.Sum(x => x.factor) <= 10
                            orderby lists.Sum(x => x.cost) descending
                            select lists).ToList();

List<Product> tempList = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to return a single list from the available lists where the conditions hold true. The code attached is returning nulls.

Thanks

Comment: What's ListOfList ?

Comment: If you're not familiar with the LINQ queries, why using them? Use `foreach` loops.

Comment: Hi, the ListOfList is a list of List<Product>.

Comment: My larger list has 4 million results so a for loop is taking too long

Comment: Straight code isn't going to work if the query doesn't return any data.  Try without the where and see if you get any results.   The query looks good so I suspect there is something wrong with the data.  Usually the data doesn't match the WHERE clause so always try without filtering first and then slowly add you filters.

Comment: LINQ is nothing but a syntactic sugar for `foreach` loops. So LINQ will be *no faster* than a well implemented loops logic.

Comment: Thought it might be faster if there was some kind of indexing of the data going on, rather than looping through each and every item. Will try jdweng's suggestion (it still needs to be returning the results I want)

Comment: @dymanoid Not very true... under a certain number of data and a complexity, linq will go same speed or lower as foreach. But on lots of data with complexity, Linq is marvelous. It's essential nowadays for access to databases to go over SQL.

Comment: @Keegan Your query works on my computer. Do you want a list of products, taking the first list, or one product with the higher cost for the result ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier, you're talking about LINQ-to-SQL - that's a different story. I'm talking about LINQ-to-objects, which is used by the OP here.

Comment: @dymanoid I'm talking about linq to object too.

Comment: @OlivierRogier, LINQ-to-objects will be *under no circumstances* faster than `foreach` loops. If you want we can continue on a chat.

Comment: @dymanoid So Linq is good for what? Only to not write loops and saturate the CPU with lots of procedure calls and burn the stack? It's useless? [System.Linq.Enumerable](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) {and that is only the surface}

Comment: @Olivier Rogier  It's the 1st list where the sum of the costs of the products in the list is Max(). Will have a look at the solutions below and give feedback. Thanks

Comment: I'd still like to test out what happens in this scenario using linq. If it's just as slow, I shall say so.

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko had an elegant looking solution on here earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you right, you are looking for `ArgMax` (*Argument* such that collection reaches its *Maximum* value on it),
*standard Linq* doesn't provide such a method, but it can be emulated with a help of `Aggregate`:

```
List<List<Product>> data = ...

List<Product> result = data
  .Select(list => new {
     list,                                    // list
     max = list
       .Where(product => product.Factor < 10) 
       .Sum(product => product.cost)          // with criterium to maximize
   })
  .Aggregate((s, a) => s.max > a.max ? s : a) // ArgMax implementation
  .list;                                      // We want list only (without max)
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. My for loop took 40 mins to query the inner list previously. This solution works in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<Product> list1 = new List<Product>() { new Product(1), new Product(3), new Product(2), new Product(6), new Product(5)};
        List<Product> list2 = new List<Product>() { new Product(14), new Product(10), new Product(8), new Product(6), new Product(1) };
        List<Product> list3 = new List<Product>() { new Product(11), new Product(22), new Product(38), new Product(14), new Product(155) }; 
        List<List<Product>> products = new List<List<Product>>() { list1, list2, list3 }; //just some dummy data

        var highestSumOfPrices = products.Max(lp => lp.Sum(p => p.Cost));

        var result = products
            .FirstOrDefault(lp => lp.Sum(p => p.Cost) == highestSumOfPrices);
```

what we do here is:
first we take the highest sum of all prices in the list of lists.
then we take the first list that match the condition: the sum of the list's products cost is equal to the highest of all the lists in the collection.
I hope this works for you. 
alternatively you can try:

```
var result = products.OrderByDescending(pl=>pl.Sum(p=>p.Cost)).First();
```

you can order (descending order) the list of lists by the sum of the costs of their products, and just take the first result; this is the simpler solution, works just as well but I cant say anything about performance

Comment: This looks quite compact actually. This would also be a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this test code with your query and it works.

```
static void Test()
{
  // Test data
  var ListOfList = new List<List<Product>>();
  var list1 = new List<Product>();
  list1.Add(new Product { name = "item 1", factor = 1, cost = 10 });
  list1.Add(new Product { name = "item 2", factor = 5, cost = 20 });
  var list2 = new List<Product>();
  list2.Add(new Product { name = "item 3", factor = 30, cost = 50 });
  list2.Add(new Product { name = "item 4", factor = 4, cost = 40 });
  var list3 = new List<Product>();
  list3.Add(new Product { name = "item 5", factor = 2, cost = 100 });
  list3.Add(new Product { name = "item 6", factor = 3, cost = 150 });
  var list4 = new List<Product>();
  list4.Add(new Product { name = "item 5", factor = 2, cost = 60 });
  list4.Add(new Product { name = "item 6", factor = 3, cost = 5 });
  ListOfList.Add(list1);
  ListOfList.Add(list2);
  ListOfList.Add(list3);
  ListOfList.Add(list4);
  // Query
  var query = ( from list in ListOfList
                where list.Sum(x => x.factor) <= 10
                orderby list.Sum(x => x.cost) descending
                select list ).FirstOrDefault();
  // Display results
  if ( query != null )
    foreach ( var item in query )
      Console.WriteLine($"{item.name} cost {item.cost} with factor {item.factor}");
}

class Product
{
  public string name;
  public int factor;
  public int cost;
}
```

**Results**

```
item 5 cost 100 with factor 2
item 6 cost 150 with factor 3
```

Comment: Thanks Olivier. My issue was to do with casting the query back to List<product>.